# Custom Formatting for a class

Tags: serilog

I'm using Serilog currently and I would like to be able to pass a class to the logger and have it log in a custom format before it outputs to a textfile. Somewhat similar to [IFormatProvider](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#format-providers). I have also found `ITextFormatter` but I am not sure if that would be the right thing to implement. Would I want a custom sink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For primitive types, Serilog [supports `IFormatProvider`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#format-providers) directly.

Most user-defined reference types however won't be passed directly to the sink by Serilog. This is because sinks often operate asynchronously, and Serilog can't assume that arbitrary user-defined types are thread-safe.

You can circumvent this, in order to use an `IFormatProvider`, by capturing values of the type as "scalars":

```
.Destructure.AsScalar<SomeClass>()
```

Or, alternatively, you can "destructure" the class into whatever secondary representation you want at the time of logging:

```
.Destructure.ByTransforming<SomeClass>(sc => Display(sc))
```

For this (`ByTransforming()`) to work, you need to opt-in with `@` when the object is logged:

```
Log.Information("Hello {@Something}", new SomeClass());
```

Simplest of all, you could also just override `ToString()` in the class itself.

Comment: Just a follow up question; if I want to use the destructure example, or overwriting ToString, I still simply add my object into my log using log.Error("{myObj}", myObj); and I should see the output I expect?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.