# How can I override Serilog's use of ToString on Guid (or other built-in primitives)?

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I'm using **Serilog** for logging a multiplayer game with Guid as the identifier for players.

The logging is more noisy than I prefer, so I'm looking to trim it down for some sinks. Typically only the first 8 digits of a Guid are needed by humans (ie - me) to debug issues. I've written an extension method for Guid called `ShortForm()`, and I'd like Serilog Console, File, and Slack sinks to use this, instead of the full Guid.

```
public static string ShortForm(this Guid guid)
{
    if (guid == Guid.Empty) 
        return "????????";
    return guid.ToString().Substring(0, 8);
}
```

I tried using `Destructure.ByTransforming()` in the constructor but it didn't seem to work:

```
string _outputTemplate = "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3}] {@m}\n{@x}";
ExpressionTemplate _consoleExpression = new ExpressionTemplate(_outputTemplate, theme: TemplateTheme.Literate);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().
   ... etc snipped ...
   Destructure.ByTransforming<Guid>(g => g.ShortForm()).
   WriteTo.Console(formatter: _consoleExpression).
   CreateLogger();
```

In my codebase:

```
//code
Log.Information("{@Guid} disconnected from {IP}", removedGuid, serverEvent.EndPoint); 

//console output
[12:30:54 INF] 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 disconnected from 127.0.0.1:59548

//or, if authenticated:
[12:34:01 INF] 3babffd8-68cb-41c2-87b6-d2beffbd431b disconnected from 127.0.0.1:51933
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Look at this answer, imho it's what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208188/174324

Comment: Ah, that's it. I didn't realize that the @ operator was required for "Destructure.ByTransforming" - In retrospect, that seems obvious, since the @ operator is literally the "destructure operator". Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work.  

Log.Information("{@Guid} disconnected from {IP}", removedGuid, serverEvent.EndPoint);

Rendered as: 

[09:52:08 INF] 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 disconnected from 127.0.0.1:64805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up a Serilog's repository and found that Guid processed as a Scalar type and no ways to use .Destructure.ByTransforming to transform it. You may look at https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/697a23189e3068bfe0da1460a2676913239d2757/src/Serilog/Capturing/PropertyValueConverter.cs#L45.

But you can use a custom formatter to format your Guid to String (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#format-providers).

I have made a little test - https://gist.github.com/sergey-miryanov/544b8413da70a0be455ac3903c1a781c